# evince not opening PDF files

Tags: centos-5, evince

On my CentOS 5.5 machine, *evince*  is not working. I cannot open PDF files. I tried to kill to restart it, but I couldn't find its PID.

Here is what I get when I launch it from the terminal:

```
[huangchao@ising download]$ evince EMBS-98-1.pdf &
[3] 23605
[huangchao@ising download]$
** (evince:23605): WARNING **: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken
```

UPDATE: After *su root*, I used *killall evince* to terminate the evince-related processes, and now I can  open PDF files from terminal under root, but I got the following messages (I still cannot open PDFs under my own account):

```
(evince:24395): GnomeUI-WARNING **: While connecting to session manager:
Authentication Rejected, reason : None of the authentication protocols specified are supported and host-based authentication failed.

** (evince:24395): WARNING **: Service registration failed.

** (evince:24395): WARNING **: Did not receive a reply. Possible causes include: the remote application did not send a reply, the message bus security policy blocked the reply, the reply timeout expired, or the network connection was broken.
Launching a SCIM daemon with Socket FrontEnd...
Loading simple Config module ...
Creating backend ...
Reading pinyin phrase lib failed
Loading socket FrontEnd module ...
Starting SCIM as daemon ...

[1]+  Done                    evince revision.pdf
```

Comment: Can you execute it from the terminal and post the output?

Comment: @André Please see the edited question. Thanks!

Comment: @Darael Please see the updated question, thank you!

Comment: @chaohuang Yeah, I saw it just after I posted the comment.  Deleted the comment because it was redundant.  That output looks pretty much like what I'd expect executing `evince` as root when someone else has the only active graphical login (root doesn't have a GNOME session running, and that's what most of the messages are).  Has the output when trying to run `evince` from the terminal as thy own user changed since killing the old instances?

Comment: @Darael No, it's the same as in the question.